Changing size of controls in Visual Studio
I am using Visual Studio (programming in C++) on a rather smallish screen. I have adjusted the font in the editor so I can work comfortably with it, but when I type Ctrl+F so search for something, the search window that pops up is minuscule, and I have serious trouble seeing what I type in it. Also, its rightmost part (where the arrows are) hides under some other parts of the display.
What am I doing wrong, and how do I make things better so I can get back to my real work?

